# Adjust cell to text in multicolumn

Tags: tabularx

I want to force the columns 2,4 and 6 to fix the width of the content (like column 2) but I can't get the same results for columns 4 and 6. What's the problem?

```
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|p{10pt}|X|p{10pt}|X|p{10pt}|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Activo: Sistema de generacion de vapor} \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Funcion} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Falla Funcional\newline(Perdida de la funcion)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Modo de Falla\newline(Causa de la falla)} \\ 
\hline 
Evaporar el agua mediante el calor suministrado por el sistema de combustión en horno. & 1 & No suministra vapor a los servicios & A & No hay fuego en el hogar & 1 \\ 
 & & & & Problema de fuga & 2 \\
 & & & & Problema de fuga & 3\\
 & & & & Problema de fuga & 4 \\
 \cline{3-6}
 &   & Bajo suministro de vapor a los servicios & B & Problema de fuga & 1 \\
 & & &  & Problema de fuga & 2 \\
\hline  
Contener el agua suministrada por el sistema de alimentación y el vapor de proceso que se genera en su interior. & 2 & Perdida de contencion & A & E & F \\
\hline 
Aliviar la presión al interior del sistema en caso de exceder la presion de trabajo llegue a un nivel critico. & 3 & C & D & E & F \\
\hline 
\end{tabularx}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem here is the `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{..}` for your headers, which stretch wider than the `Xp{10pt}` column. You need to wrap those headers, or do something else altogether...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with the `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks inside cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\setcellgapes{4pt}

\begin{document}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{3}{X|p{10pt}|}}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Activo: Sistema de generacion de vapor} \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Funcion} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Falla Funcional\\(Perdida de la funcion)}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{Modo de Falla\\(Causa de la falla)}} \\
  \hline
  \parbox[t][0pt]{\hsize}{Evaporar el agua mediante el calor suministrado por el sistema de combustión en horno.} & 1 & \parbox[t][0pt]{\hsize}{No suministra vapor a los servicios} & A & No hay fuego en el hogar & 1 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Problema de fuga & 2 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Problema de fuga & 3 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Problema de fuga & 4 \\
  \cline{3-6}
                                                                                                                    & & \parbox[t][0pt]{\hsize}{Bajo suministro de vapor a los servicios} & B & Problema de fuga & 1 \\
                                                                                                                    & & & & Problema de fuga & 2 \\
  \hline
  Contener el agua suministrada por el sistema de alimentación y el vapor de proceso que se genera en su interior. & 2 & Perdida de contencion & A & E & F \\
  \hline
  Aliviar la presión al interior del sistema en caso de exceder la presion de trabajo llegue a un nivel critico. & 3 & C & D & E & F \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can u read minds? You fixed all my problems . Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to feel useful!